# how to query where date with time = date without time in ms sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to do a query with dates this is my sample tsql:

```
select * from Bookings where StartTime = '2/15/2014'
```

the starttime has value '2/15/2014 12:00:00 AM'

when I query where StartTime = date with no time the result is 0

Anybody can help how to do this?

thanks

Comment: Is STartTime a VarChar? if yes convert String to Date and compare

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare with only dates and ignore time in where clause in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955656/how-to-compare-with-only-dates-and-ignore-time-in-where-clause-in-sql-server-200): one of the few answers that rightly suggest a range check. Nearly all answers jump on non-sargable solutions by converting the column value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT * FROM  Bookings WHERE Convert(VARCHAR(10),StartTime,101) =  Convert(Varchar(10),'2/15/2014',101)
```

If you are using SQL SERVER 2012

Try this

```
 SELECT * FROM  Bookings WHERE FORMAT(StartTime,'M/dd/yyyy') = FORMAT('2/15/2014','M/dd/yyyy')
```

## [SQL FORMAT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

Comment: thanks, This one works. but the idea is from you shared thanks again
SELECT * FROM  Bookings WHERE FORMAT(StartTime,'M/dd/yyyy') ='2/15/2014'

Answer (score 13):

The best way to do this is with a simple comparison:

```
select *
from Bookings
where StartTime >= cast('2014-02-15' as date) and StartTime < cast('2014-02-14' as date);
```

This is the safest method of comparison, because it will take advantage of an index on `StartTime`.  This property is called "sargability".

In SQL Server, casting to a `date` should also be sargable, so you could also do:

```
select *
from Bookings
where cast(StartTime as date) = cast('2014-02-15' as date) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

'2/15/2014' can be interpreted different depending on your locale.  Try using the ISO date literal '2014-02-15', which is independent of the locale.

```
select * from Bookings where StartTime = '2014-02-15'
```

Or if StartTime includes hours:

```
select * from Bookings where StartTime >= '2014-02-15' and StartTime < '2014-02'16'
```

Answer (score 1):

I  believe you could also do this:

```
select * from Bookings where StartTime::date = '2014-2-15'
```