# How to compare with only dates and ignore time in where clause in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a column `Expiry_Date` with date and time values in `table1`.

I am sending a date value from the front end using C#.

I write the query to get some information if where condition is true.

For ex: in `table1`, `Expiry_Date` has the value `2016-03-11 23:59:59.000`

```
select USER_NAME, USER_EMAIL 
from table1 
where Expiry_Date = '2016-03-12';
```

When I execute this, I am not getting any results. Actually the table has the data for this date, due to not having time part in supplied date, it's not matching with `Expiry_Date`.

So please let me know how can we do this without passing time from front end.

Comment: Look at `CAST(Expiry_Date AS DATE)` . It should convert your DateTime to Date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two DATETIME only by date not time in SQL Server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1843395/compare-two-datetime-only-by-date-not-time-in-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 2):

don't use cast() or convert() on the column in where clause. It will give not give you good performance. Use this instead

```
where Expiry_Date >= '2016-03-12'
and   Expiry_Date < DATEADD(DAY, 1, '2016-03-12')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cast `Expiry_Date` to `Date` in your where clause...

```
select USER_NAME, USER_EMAIL 
from table1 
where (CAST Expiry_Date AS DATE) = '2016-03-12';
```

This should return all the record with expiry date '2016-03-12' of any time.