# How to cast a datetime format to date as string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, casting, varchar

I am struggling to find a solution for the below issue.

```
date1 = 31-08-2017 12:10:00
```

I want to cast it as string and need to take date (31-08-2017) alone.

This is my SQL statement:

```
select * 
from table_name  
where cast(date1 as varchar) = '2017-08-30'
```

Here '2017-08-30' is string; when I ran the above select command it's showing o records as date1 is `varchar` but time also is included.

Can anyone tell me how to split date column alone as a string?

Comment: If you have any option whatsoever at this stage, you need to stop storing dates in `varchar`, and convert existing data into a data data type also

Comment: Please post the real query you are using , and table DDL so we know that the column data type is. I assume `date1` is a table column in your example.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : it's 6 years later and this poster's account appears to be dead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare with only dates and ignore time in where clause in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35955656/how-to-compare-with-only-dates-and-ignore-time-in-where-clause-in-sql-server-200): None of the answerers care about sargability. This should be done by a range check, see the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

this will help you :-

```
select * from table_name  WHERE CONVERT(varchar(23), [YourDateColumn], 121)= '2017-08-30 00:00:00.000'
```

above will accept both date and time

if you want to use only date then try this :-

```
   select * from table_name  WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), [YourDateColumn], 20)= '2017-08-30 00:00:00.000'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

select * from transaction_data.ft_raw_movio_transaction  WHERE CONVERT(varchar(23), utc_transaction_datetime, 121)= '2017-08-30 00:00:00.000'

its showing syntax error
 Invalid operation: syntax error at or near ",";

Comment: i did like below its working.
CAST( (CAST(utc_transaction_datetime AS date)) AS varchar)

Comment: @Manimekalai query is right, I have checked.Kindly check once

Comment: here you have to use `cast` twice. but using `convert` it will be easy.

Comment: select count(*) from transaction_data.ft_raw_movio_transaction WHERE CONVERT(char(10),utc_transaction_datetime, 20) like '2017-08-31%'

its showing error
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near ",";
1 statement failed.

Comment: it's working fine for me it returned count .could you please share screen shot for the same ?

Answer (score 0):

If your `date1`'s type is DateTime, Try this,

```
select * 
from table_name  
where CAST(date1 AS DATE) = CAST('2017-08-30' AS DATE)
```

Comment: its working fine when we run in redshift database when i try to run.

same when i try to run in aws unload, getting below error.

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "2017"
LINE 1: ...re CAST(utc_transaction_datetime AS date) = CAST('2017-08-31...

Comment: I guess you may need to use escape character for single quote, like `= CAST(\'2017-08-30\' AS DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
select * 
from table_name   
Where CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),date1,102) = '2017.08.30'
```

date1 is column name value= `'30-08-2017 12:10:00'`

Output will be `30-08-2017`