# SQL query datetimes in a given day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table named "event" and the column I'm focusing on is named "start", it is DateTime-formated.
I simply need to fetch, in this table, all events which "start" date is within a given date's **day**.

For instance, here is a set of dates:

- 2016-10-17 08:00:00
- 2016-10-17 12:30:00
- 2016-10-18 09:15:00

My query in plain English would be: "Select all events where the start date is on the same day as '2016-10-17 16:45:27' ". The database should then return both first entries.

What I'm wondering is if there are some SQL functions which could do that or if I should use som code in my PHP page to compute stuff and create a completely diffrent query... Any help is welcome!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [Date()](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp) function extracts the date part of a date or date/time
>   expression.

```
"SELECT * FROM `event` WHERE date(start) = date('2016-10-17 16:45:27')";
```

Comment: Indeed, I spent so much time thinking about it that I forgot about the basics. Thank you so much!

Comment: Always Welcome `:)` @QuentinLamotte

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21745053/4493079) answer

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE Convert(VARCHAR(10),start,101) =  Convert(Varchar(10),'21/10/2016',101)
```